# WPF "flying" combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

is it possible to create a combobox in wpf from code, which I could position wherever I want on the window?
In my case, I basically want to create something like a Autocomplete for DataGrid rows,...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TextBox supports auto complete, and you can create your datagrid's template column and you can specify the template with textbox which can interact and give you autocompletion.

Comment: Thats not what I need. I have a Datagrid and want to position the Combobox under whatever row I want,....

Answer (score 0):

if you put it in a `<Popup>` you can then position the popup wherever you want--it is not "bound" by a parent container.